# How to remove the FPS text on slick2d?

Tags: java, slick

How do I remove the frame rate text on the upper left corner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setShowFPS(false)` from [GameContainer](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/GameContainer.html). Use google (great tool trust me) and [RTFM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM). Do you make a bit of research before asking here, you could save a lot time by simply typing *slick2d hide fps* in google.

Please accept the answers you got.